# Is there a way to create a list of callbacks to be done in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, callback, event-handling, slider

I have a program with multiple sliders, and there is a function called `slider.on_changed()` that allows to check if the amplitude of the slider has changed.

Right now I have the following:

```py
slider1.on_changed(update)
slider2.on_changed(update)
```

However, I want to have `n` sliders. Is there a way to create a list of callbacks depending on `n`? Something like this:

```
if n == 2:
    slider1.on_changed(update)
    slider2.on_changed(update)
elif n == 3:
    slider1.on_changed(update)
    slider2.on_changed(update)
    slider3.on_changed(update)
```

I don't know exactly what I could try.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your sliders in a list:

```
sliders = [slider1, slider2, slider3, ...]
```

And then call N times their function:

```
for i in range(N):
    sliders[i].on_changed(update)
```